# no access control allow origin in angular 4

Tags: angular

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

```
request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.authToken
          },
        });
```

at back-end server we are setting allow cross origin as following

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    System.out.println("Request header: " + request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
```

but still we are getting no access control allow origin  present on requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 6. It supports proxy-config.json which will proxy your backend API. It's used only for development.  For more details , please refer his link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: i m using angular 4. and i dont want to use webpack dev server. if you could provide me with some other solution it will be great thnk you